# Add line after button click

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code (which works) where the user fills out a form and hits a button. The VBA then takes what's in that form and transfers the data to another spreadsheet.

Here is part of the code, which I believe shows all that applies to this operation (the entire code is several hundred lines):

```
Sub Task_Entry()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim InstalDesc As String
Dim AssignedTo As String
Dim Model As Range
Dim Drawing As Range
Dim Index As Long
Dim m As Long, n As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Copy data from the input screen to the task list.
Sheets("Task Entry Form").Select
InstalDesc = Range("D3")
AssignedTo = Range("G2")
Set Model = Range("D5", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
Set Drawing = Range("I5", Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
```

I'm learning VBA, so if that's not enough information to do what I'm asking, let me know and I'll add whatever parts I'm missing, but I believe this is the part controlling the transfer of data and (again) this is working right now.

What I would like to happen now is, when the user hits the button, it takes all the data (as it currently does) but ADDS a line that says "Machining".

i.e., when the data is transferred to the next worksheet, the *last line will always be* "Machining", even if it's not in the list when they hit the button.

Edit for clarity: Right now, the End user fills out a form on a worksheet. On that form they list several models and drawings that they know they're going to complete for a task. Then they hit the button and the VBA code takes the data and puts it into a task tracker, so it moves the models to the model column on the task tracker, puts the drawings in the drawing columns, etc.

However, every task has machining as a requirement. To ensure they don't forget to add this task, I want the VBA to add it after they hit the button. So, they hit the button, the VBA takes all the data on the form, adds "machining" as if the end user typed it in the form, and places the form's data with the word machining over to the task list.

I hope that clarifies any confusion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you ask. Where would you like the text "Machining" to appear exactly? What is the obstacle that prevents you from putting it there? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Sure, sorry if I wasn't clear. I'll edit original message with more detail.